# How can I add to the extended properties collection of a build in Azure Devops pipelines

Tags: .net, rest, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using the .NET client libraries for Azure DevOps to get information about my builds and display them on a website. I want to get the assembly version of my application that is being built to display on the web site.

I see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/properties?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) that there is a collection of arbitrary key-value pairs that I can get via the REST API (and also with the dotnet client library). But how do I **set** these properties during my build?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get the assembly version of my application that is being built to display on the web site.

For the assembly version knowing, use either of the tools like [ILDASM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler?redirectedfrom=MSDN), [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy#ilspy-------), [Reflector](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) or Jetbrains dotpeek.

ILDASM will be available in the path of:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\ildasm.exe
```

where v8.1A is installed Windows SDK's version.

ILDASM:
Ildasmtooltoseeversion

[image]

[image]

> how do I set these properties during my build?
> You need to set extended properties in the form of environment variables.

> > You can use variables with expressions to conditionally assign values and further customize pipelines. Refer to Microsoft [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Use this YAML task template called SetBuildProperties.yml to add build properties in a pipeline:

SetBuildProperties.yml:

```
# Sets custom build properties. Use this to transfer info between pipelines.
parameters:

- name: buildId
  type: string

steps:
  
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Set build properties'
  name: 'SetBuildProperties'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |

        # prepare the auth token
        $authHeader = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"

        $requestHeader = @{
            "Authorization" = $authHeader
            "Accept" = "application/json"
        }

        # array of operations
        # @{} is a hashtable in PowerShell. 
        # @() is an array (list) in PowerShell.
        $paramsObject = 
        @(
            @{
                "op" = "add"
                "path" = "/myProperty"
                "value" = "myValue"
            }
        )

        $params = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $paramsObject

        Write-Host "JSON: " $params

        $contentType = "application/json-patch+json;charset=utf-8"        


        $apiurl = "https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg/MyProject/_apis/build/builds/${{ parameters.buildId }}/properties?api-version=6.0"
        
        Write-Host "Invoking REST API url: " $apiurl

        try 
        {
            $properties = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiurl -Method PATCH -Headers $requestHeader -Body $params -ContentType $contentType

        }
        catch
        {
            # Writes an error to build summary and to log in red text
            Write-Host "##vso[task.LogIssue type=error;]Error occurred: " $_

            exit 1
        }
```

If you need to read the properties in the same or a different pipeline you can use this template GetBuildProperties.yml:

```
# Gets custom build properties. Use this to transfer info between pipelines.
parameters:

- name: buildId
  type: string

steps:
  
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Get build properties'
  name: 'GetBuildProperties'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |

        # prepare the auth token
        $authHeader = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"

        $requestHeader = @{
            "Authorization" = $authHeader
            "Accept" = "application/json"
        }

        $apiurl = "https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg/MyCompany/_apis/build/builds/${{ parameters.buildId }}/properties?api-version=6.0"
        
        Write-Host "Invoking REST API url: " $apiurl

        try 
        {
            $properties = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiurl -Method Get -Headers $requestHeader

            $propertiesJSON = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $properties
            Write-Host 'properties: ' $propertiesJSON
        }
        catch
        {
            # Writes an error to build summary and to log in red text
            Write-Host "##vso[task.LogIssue type=error;]Error occurred: " $_

            exit 1
        }
```